# yum fails installing php53-devel.x86_64

Tags: php, redhat, fedora, yum

I need to recompile php on a Fedora server because I need to use the --enable-zip flag.  When trying to install the devel package, I get the following message.  This is after a 'yum clean all':

```
yum install php53-devel.x86_64
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
rhel-x86_64-server-5                                                                  | 1.4    kB     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-5/primary                                                          | 4.9 MB     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-5                                                                             14161/14161
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.3-13.el5_8 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php53 = 5.3.3-13.el5_8 for package: php53-devel
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-devel-5.3.3-13.el5_8.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php53 = 5.3.3-13.el5_8 is needed by package php53-devel-5.3.3-13.el5_8.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
Error: Missing Dependency: php53 = 5.3.3-13.el5_8 is needed by package php53-devel-5.3.3-13.el5_8.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Output of 'yum repolist':

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
repo id                                               repo name                                                                           status
rhel-x86_64-server-5                                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)                                   enabled: 14,161
repolist: 14,161
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `yum repolist`?

Comment: Added.  See above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Red Hat subscription for this machine is active. Not having an active subscription is usually the cause of this. (If it *is* active, call Red Hat.)

And if you're compiling your own version of PHP, you don't need to do any of this.

Comment: I assume it is.  I installed other packages yesterday.

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't need to do any of this"?

Comment: If you're compiling PHP, you don't need to install this package first.

Answer (score 0):

If you've compiled your own PHP and it's an RPM package, either exclude the offending package from your YUM command (using --exclude=packagename) or just run an rpm installation of your newly-compiled PHP.

Comment: It's the php that was installed via yum.  I haven't compiled my own yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use another repo for PHP and php-dev packages. I'd recommend to use [atomic](http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/)